# Perl Tie::IxHash - is there an 'each' method?

Tags: perl, hash, each, tie

Tie::IxHash produces an object that has a mostly-complete set of behaviors as both an array and a hash.  But I'm not finding the equivalent of the `each` function, which returns (key,value) pairs.

Have I just overlooked it?

If I have to roll my own, I'd have thought something like this would work:

```
use Tie::IxHash;
$t = Tie::IxHash->new( a,1,b,2,c,3 );
while (($x1, $x2) =  map { $_ => $t->Values($_) } $t->Keys ) { say "$x1 => $x2"; }
```

But the output was an infinite series of

```
a => 1
```

... for reasons that aren't clear to me yet.

Anybody able to suggest how to achieve `each` with a tied hash?

Comment: Re: "But the output was an infinite series of `a => 1`": This is because `map { $_ => $t->Values($_) } $t->Keys` always evaluates to the list `(a,1,b,2,c,3)`. Your assignment sets `$x1` and `$x2` to the first two elements of this list, and discards the rest. (`each` "remembers" where in the hash you are, but your `while`-loop has nothing like that. Each iteration retrieves the whole list and discards all but the start of it.)

Comment: Yes, I see now, having read the `each` doc more carefully.  It looks like I could either beat my head up trying to write a function that maintains a persistent iterator, or just go ahead and write a `foreach` loop over `$t->Keys` and retrieve `$t->Values($key)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Tie::IxHash` doesn't have an `Each` method, but you can use Perl's `each` function on the tied hash:

```
use Tie::IxHash;
my $t = tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
@hash{qw/a b c d e/} = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

# using the tied hash
while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) {
    print "$key => $val\n";
}

# using the OO interface (interchangeably)
foreach my $key ($t->Keys) {
    my $val = $t->FETCH($key);
    print "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Note that `$t->Values($key)` won't work. This method expects an index not a key. This will work:

```
foreach (0 .. $t->Length - 1) {
    my ($key, $val) = ($t->Keys($_), $t->Values($_));
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is FETCH?  I don't see that documented.

Comment: FETCH is mentioned in the documentation as the first item in the Object interface section. It is one of the methods that are required to enable it to be used as a tied hash, along with STORE, DELETE, EXISTS and others. (See http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-Hashes and http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html)